# Dump data base from SQL using shell command from a particular date

Tags: php, mysql, database, shell

I just need to dump a db which is updating on a daily basis. I am using shell prompt for dumping, I need the dump from the present day alone. We are keeping a timestamp in one of the table we need to dump that table alone with respect to date, i.e. not including yesterdays file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question does not fit the format of this Q&A site. You need to show your effort. You need to provide evidence that you have tried to solve the problem yourself. Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Free hint: [check MySQL dump and its `where` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)

Answer (score 0):

As @Barranka mentioned, you can use the [`--where` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) of `mysqldump` to do this:

```
mysqldump [...] --where="date(saved)='2014-02-03'" [...]
```